# Can't create a docker image for COPY failed: stat /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builderXXXXXX error

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I'm not able to build my image. Below is the line that I feel as the challenge. Please have a look and suggest me if I have done anything wrong. I'm trying to copy a zip file that is present in the current folder as the Dockerfile and docker-compose file. I don't have a .dockerignore file also. I'm declaring the file name as ENV and passing that value in docker-compose file.

```
COPY ${FILE_NAME}.zip /app/
```

My docker-compose file is like this.

```
version: '3.7'
services:
    tws:
        build:
            context: .
            dockerfile: Dockerfile
        ports:
            - "8085:8085"
        environment:
            - FILE_NAME=xxxxx
```

Below is the error that come during `docker-compose up`

```
ERROR: Service 'yyy' failed to build: COPY failed: stat /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder467027701/.zip: no such file or directory
```

**EDIT:** It is working fine if I provide the actual name instead of ENV in the Dockerfile

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that what you need is a build argument because you perform the `COPY` task at the build time and not at the container start time.
Remove that part :

```
environment:
   - FILE_NAME=xxxxx
```

And update your compose such as :

```
build:
   args:
     - FILE_NAME=xxxxx
```

And declare the `ARG` in the Dockerfile :

```
FROM ...
ARG FILE_NAME
...
COPY ${FILE_NAME}.zip /app/
```

Comment: You are a life save. Thanks!